# Cakephp 2.4 Login won't work in IE and Safari

Tags: cakephp, authentication, internet-explorer-8, safari, cakephp-2.4

I make an app with Cakephp but when i try to login from IE 8 or Safari it won't work (I can login from chrome and firefox).

I just use the login method of Auth component in my UsersController, I check in both beforeFilter (AppController and UsersController) and I pass trough them with a good Auth->user() and Users/index in my params[controller/action] (where I have to be redirect when login success) but just after I'm redirect to the login page with an empty Auth->user(), I don't understand why.

Sorry for my english and thanks you for your help.

- I found the reason, but I don't know why and what to do... I actually have a domain name "www.domain.com" wich redirect to the IP of a remote server where is located the app. If I log from the domain the session is destroy at each page but if I log from the IP of the server where is the app it works.

Comment: The typical reason is a 404 request being processed as a controller action and invalidating the session (because you're hammering your application with requests) - check the tmp/error.log for evidence of that.

Comment: I found the reason ! but I don't know why and what to do... I actually have a domain name "www.domain.com" wich redirect to the IP of a remote server where is located the app. If I log from the domain the session is destroy at each page but if I log from the IP of the server where is the app it works.

Comment: Is it a secret special reason that nobody else can know about?

Comment: x) Sorry i just edit i push "enter" for new line but he submit my answer

Comment: hah - ok. Please _edit the question_ don't add details using comments.